# Designing a class representing a network in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing some numerical experiments in TensorFlow that involve creating some simple networks and seeing how well they can approximate various functions.

My first thought was to make a different Python class for each type of network I'm comparing. But I think the way I'm writing my classes is flawed. For instance, my first one is called `AffineNetwork`. It has a method for training the network, and a method for simply feeding an input through the network.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class AffineNetwork:
    def __init__(self, trainingData, targets, initialParams):
        self.trainingData = trainingData
        self.targets = targets
        self.weights = tf.get_variable("weights",  initializer = tf.constant(initialParams[0]))
        self.bias = tf.get_variable("bias",  initializer = tf.constant(initialParams[1]))
        self.outputs = tf.expand_dims(self.weights,0) @ trainingData + self.bias
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.targets - self.outputs))
        self.optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
        self.train_step = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss)
        self.init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar("loss", self.loss)

    def train(self, max_iter, directory_name):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(self.init)
            writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("Tensorboard/" + directory_name)
            for step in range(max_iter):
                sess.run(self.train_step)
                summ = sess.run(self.loss_summary)
                writer.add_summary(summ, step)
            writer.close()       

    def feedforward(self, x):
        if len(x.shape) == 1:
            x = tf.expand_dims(x, 1)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(self.init)
            return sess.run(tf.expand_dims(self.weights,0) @ x + self.bias)
```

I think this way of organizing things is flawed, because:

- Suppose I train my network parameters, and then I want to use these to make predictions. I have to do this within the same TensorFlow session, or else everything will be wiped out, and I'll be starting fresh. (**Question:** *Is this statement correct?*)

If that is correct, it would seem that it wouldn't make sense to split up these functions between two methods, because the session would close in between them.

For reference, what I'm trying to do with this class is something like the following script. It trains the network on a constant function, and then compare its first prediction and its prediction after training.

```
dim = 3
dataSetSize = 5
trainingData = np.array(np.arange(15).astype(np.float32).reshape(dim, dataSetSize))
targets = np.ones(dataSetSize, dtype = np.float32)
initialParams = [np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, dim).astype(np.float32), np.float32(0)]
myAffineNetwork = nt.AffineNetwork(trainingData, targets,initialParams)
print(myAffineNetwork.feedforward(np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float32)))
myAffineNetwork.train(50, output_folder_name)
print(myAffineNetwork.feedforward(np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float32)))
```

But it's spitting out the same thing before and after training.

**Question:** What would be the usual, smarter way of organizing these things? My idea about having a different class for each architecture of network: do I need to abandon that idea altogether? Or just write the methods in a smarter way?

Answer (score 1):

Defining a class for a network is not a bad idea. Danijar ([LINK](https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/)) states that all models in the TensorFlow codebase are defined this way.

To tackle your problem, you could do several things. Firstly, when you define the `__init__()` method, you could define a session for the object:

```
class AffineNetwork:
def __init__(self, trainingData, targets, initialParams):
    self.trainingData = trainingData
    self.targets = targets
    self.weights = tf.get_variable("weights",  initializer = tf.constant(initialParams[0]))
    self.bias = tf.get_variable("bias",  initializer = tf.constant(initialParams[1]))
    self.outputs = tf.expand_dims(self.weights,0) @ trainingData + self.bias
    self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.targets - self.outputs))
    self.optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
    self.train_step = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss)
    self.init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    self.loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar("loss", self.loss)

    self.sess = tf.Session()
```

This way, you have the same session available for all your operations. You have to adapt the rest of your code though, e.g. use `self.sess.run()` for evaluating your operations.

Another option would be that you train the model in a session, save it to disk, and restore it in another session to do inference. That answers your first question, as different sessions do wipe out information, but it can be stored on disk (which makes sense considering that you don't wanna train every time before you do inference once).

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion, should I be paranoid about the session staying open for too long? I.e. as long as the class instance is in scope? People have always warned me to close my sessions quickly.

Comment: It is hard to define a general rule on how to handle this, as it depends on your usage of the class instance. For relatively small examples like this I haven't run into issues yet. If you want to make sure that you close the session, you can add `self.sess.close()` at some point after finishing work with the instance.